# Determining width of a UIView using autolayout - SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, width

Alright so in the interface builder (`Main.storyboard`), I have a `containerView:UIView` embedded in a `UIScrollView`. Within in the `containerView` I want to create additional `UIView`'s to hold blocks of content such as a header, body, etc. The reason for doing it like this, is so that the content can scroll vertically but not horizontally.

My goal is to use autolayout to create these different `UIView`'s. As of right now the containerView automatically adjusts it's width depending on the screen size of the device being used, as to prevent horizontal scrolling. It does this using an IBOutlet I created for the width constraint. It currently looks like so:

```
@IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!
@IBOutlet var containerViewWidthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Prevents horizontal scrolling
    containerViewWidthConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.size.width

    createHeader()
}
```

Then I created a function called `createheader{}` which pins a `headerView:UIView` at the top of the `containerView`, and 8 points from either edge of the `containerView`:

```
func createHeader() {
    //Create header
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.containerView.addSubview(headerView)

    //Create header constraints
    let leftMargin = NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerView, attribute: .Leading, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8)
    let rightMargin = NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .Trailing, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: headerView, attribute: .Trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 8)
    let topMargin = NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: containerView, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 70)
    let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: headerView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 160)

    //Activate header constraints
    headerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leftMargin,rightMargin,topMargin,heightConstraint])

    println(headerView.frame.size.width)
}
```

Now since the size of the content inside the `headerView` will be dependent on the screen size of the device being used, I want to be able to create functions that size the width of the content depending on the size of the width of the `headerView` itself. However every time I try to grab the width of the `headerView` using:

```
println(headerView.frame.size.width)
```

It returns a value of zero, which is obviously not the case because it is still creating a blue-background `headerView` according to the constraints above.

Why is SWIFT not recognizing that the `headerView` has a width? And how can I grab the width of the `headerView`?

Comment: As of right now I'm relating back to the `containerView` to grab the width: `(containerView.frame.size.width - 16)`. I still don't understand why the `headerView` is recognized as having no width....

Comment: Why don't you just add constraints to your new content inside 'headerView'?

Comment: That's the plan but how could I if the `headerView` is recognized as having no width? For example, I wanted to place a squared image that is automatically resized and centered inside the `headerView`. This is done by using a 1:1 aspect ratio constraint and two equal horizontal constraints, one `.Trailing` and one `.Leading`. But when I went to create the horizontal constraints that relate back to the `headerView`'s width... `headerView.frame.size.width / 3.5`, this value kept coming back as 0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing constraints you need to call `layoutIfNeeded` if you want to update the frames immediately.

```
func createHeader() {
    //Create header
    let headerView = UIView()
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    self.containerView.addSubview(headerView)

    ...

    //Activate header constraints
    headerView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([leftMargin,rightMargin,topMargin,heightConstraint])

    self.containerView.layoutIfNeeded() // Updates the frames
    println(headerView.frame.size.width) // Will output the correct width
}
```

Note that this will happen automatically on the next iteration of the UI loop which is, however, not helpful to you when you want to see the effects immediately.